# Add unlimited number of actors on stage (libGDX)

Tags: java, libgdx

**H**ow can I add unlimited image (Actor) which player add any number of image he want on stage **?**

**For Example:** Suppose the actor is this image [image]
,  and the player want to add it from any point to any point on the stage coordinates. I as developer I don't know how many images which player want to be added on stage.

- Maybe, 5 images

[image]

- Maybe, 4 images

[image]

I know the following code not complete : (in render method)

```
 Vector2 position = stage.screenToStageCoordinates(new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY()));
 image.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
 stage.addActor(image);
```

Anyone have Idea .. ?

Comment: What's the actual problem here? The code looks like you know how to add an actor based on user input and Stage doesn't have any hard limits on how many actors there may be.

Comment: the summary, I want the player who adds unlimited number of the actor, not me. i.e. (The Player As Developer)

Comment: like `The Strategy Games`. The player add many buildings. If he has many coins or a lot of mony or ... etc. , he can builds more and more of buildings. (unlimited number of buildings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no limit on the Stage about actors count (although you should notice that to many actors can affect the performance) so you just can create them in the render method as you wrote. If you want to create them **on user input and on some conditions** you should use **InputListener**

The thing is to create a button like "Buil House" and onClick on it check if player has enough money **then create new actor and add it to stage** - important thing is that you **cannot add the same actor twice**

```
     Button button = new Button(skin, "buildButton");

     button.addListener(buildListener);

     ...

     ClickListener buildListener = new ClickListener()
            {
                public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) 
                {
                    if( cash > BUILDING_COST )
                    {
                        Image building = createBuildig(); //it can be also some class inherits actor if you want it to have some more informations
                        building.setPosition(position.x, position.y); //some position

                        //you can also add actor to some array to process it lateer somehow...

                        stage.addActor( building );
                    }
                }
    };
```

Comment: WOW, you did it with a simple code. I was think should create a list with unknown size. How this idea has not crossed my mind :D. THANX A LOT
see your answer in this my [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypek0iqK8v0&feature=youtu.be) . THANX AGAIN :) .